# Liquibase-Hibernate: How to set a Unique Constraint spanning over two tables through a JoinTable?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, liquibase

I have a table **Container** which may have N **Items**, linked through a join table and each Item has a property Type. Nota also that an Item can be in multiple containers.

How can I add a unique constraint, such that in a Container are not allowed two Items having the same Type?

This is the **Container** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "container")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "container")
public class Container implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "container_item",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="container_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="items_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and this is the **Item** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private Type type;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Container> containers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is the Liquibase changelog for the join table:

```
<createTable tableName="container_item">
    <column name="items_id" type="bigint">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column name="containers_id" type="bigint">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

Comment: Is there a table named "container_item" in your database?

Comment: @htshame yes, see the updated description.

Comment: So `container_item` table doesn't have `type` column, but you need to include it in constraint?

Comment: Yes, adding the Type column and setting Unique(containers_id, types_id) would be enough.
But how can I configure hibernate to also populate this extra field on the join table?